# Dynamic control elements on a re-usable UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to reuse a `UITableViewController` for multiple purposes. My problem is that I'd like to display different buttons and other elements depending on the intention for displaying the list.

I'm currently using multiple cell prototypes to display different info for each item's detail, but I'd also like to be able to swap the controls depending on intention. I've been showing and hiding controls to accomplish this, but looking at the storyboard gets a bit ugly.

I was thinking maybe using a container view... just figured I throw this out there and see if anyone is doing anything similar. I didn't want to created separate list views just to change buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details, it's hard to say whether this will solve your problem particularly. However, I do precisely this in my current project and this is how:
I am going to assume the following. Let me know if they don't hold true and I'll update my answer accordingly.

- You're creating a cell prototype for every permutation and combination, including actions. And so you have too many prototype cells.
- Your actions are 'buttons' or similar controls on the cell (and not the swipe to reveal edit actions).

Create a custom class for your cell. Add a container for your actions and position it appropriately in story board. Connect the container to an outlet in the cell.

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property MyCellTypeEnum type;
-(void) configure;
@end

@implementation MyCustomCell 

-(void) configure {
  switch(type) {
    case type1:
      // add actions to container
      break;
    case type2:
      // etc.
  }
}
@end
```

And in your TableViewController's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // ... dequeue appropriate cell
  cell.type = <appropriate type>
  [cell configure];
  return cell;
}
```

Hope that helps.